# C Structs Nodes

Tags: c, struct

I was just assigned a project to do in C in my class, but my professor didn't teach anything about C, so I'm just trying to learn as I go.

How do I assign values to different parts of a node?

The main code that runs I have is: (This was given in the assignment)

```
Node n2, n3, n4, times, plus;

setNode(&n2, 2, NULL, NULL, true);
setNode(&n3, 3, NULL, NULL, true);
setNode(&n4, 4, NULL, NULL, true);

printf("\n");

setNode(&times, '*', &n3, &n4, true);
setNode(&plus,  '+', &n2, &times, true);

printf("  Tree evaluation: %d\n\n", eval(&plus));
```

and in the header file:

```
typedef struct Node_t {
    int             value;
    struct Node_t   *left;
    struct Node_t   *right;
} Node, *Node_p;
```

What I have so far for setNode is:

```
void setNode(Node_p np,
         int    value,
         Node_p left,
         Node_p right,
         bool   display) {

np->value;
}
```

How do I fill in the values for left and right? And how do I access them in another method `eval`?

I've been googling for days and can't figure out what I'm exactly looking for. I know Obj-C pretty well, but this is just over my head. Any answers or links to resources would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `Node_p` which is a pointer to a `struct Node_t`, you can access members of the object using the arrow operator (`->`).  So within the `setNode()` function, you can access `left` and `right` the same way you accessed `value` and set their values.

```
void setNode(Node_p np,
     int    value,
     Node_p left,
     Node_p right,
     bool   display) {

    np->value = value; /* sets the value field */
    np->left = left;   /* sets the left field */
    np->right = right; /* sets the right field */
    /* and so on... */
}
```

Note that the arrow operator can be used to access members if you have a pointer to any struct or union object in general.

Looking at how `eval()` was used, it looks like it takes a `Node_p` as well.  So to access the members, it's done in exactly the same way also using the arrow operator except you're probably reading values, not setting them.

e.g.,

```
void eval(Node_p np) {
    int value = np->value;    /* read the value field */
    Node_p left = np->left;   /* read the left field */
    Node_p right = np->right; /* read the right field */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You assign pointer values the same way you would normal values (Which unfortunately, you're not doing currently :) )

Your `value` should be assigned via:

```
np->value = value;
```

in your `setNode()` function.

As for how you access them, it's the same. In your `eval` you could do:

```
printf("This is my value: %d\n", np->value);
```

To get at another node, you would say:

```
Node_p anotherNodePointer = np->left;
```

Answer (score 2):

For assigning a `struct` directly (e.g. for `Node`), use:

```
var.name = value;
```

For assigning a `struct` via a pointer (e.g. for `Node`_p), use:

```
var->name = value;
```

Comment: Yeah, I can't say I care for typedefs like that. Very easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

It's this simple:

```
void setNode(Node_p np,
         int    value,
         Node_p left,
         Node_p right,
         bool   display) 
{
    np->value = value;
    np->left = left;
    np->right = right;        
}
```